# How to Connect Logic Apps with Bot Framework?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-logic-apps, azure-bot-service

I want to use the logic app functionality with the bot framework. Logic App doesn't have built-in channels to deploy. I need to deploy my logic apps at various platforms including web-chat, teams, telegram

Comment: Can you give specific example(s) of a scenario you want to support?

Comment: Logic Apps has wider connectivity with azure DevOps, outlook while on the other hand bot service is totally code-based. I want to deploy my logic app to a web-chat and thought that connecting the logic app to a bot channel would be better, and I would be able to use other channels also by doing this

Comment: The web chat is used to integrate the special rest end point on which the Bot Framework SDK works. In case you wish to expose the Logic app functionality through a bot, then in that case you will have to call the logic app end point from the bot dialog and then expose the bot over the channel.  Why would you like to expose the logic app over the bot channel? Standard practice in integration world is to expose the REST based end point directly or through a API gateway

Comment: The Bot Channel easily gives the integration with various channels and that's the only reason I want to integrate it with. The channels are ready there, and just a click behind to deploy it. Does the logic app have an endpoint? Can you please check it once?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to run your logic app as bot code, that won't be possible. You can create you A bot Channels Registration to have all the channels available to whatever endpoint you specify. But regardless, that endpoint, will need to have all the infrastructure, etc, to work with each channel connector. It might be possible to do this somehow with all the logic app [action/connectors] available out there, but you're going to have a LOT of work ahead of you in that route. There is no bot connector for logic apps. As @Mandar said, you could call the logic app from the bot, if that could get you what you need.